# Avoiding boilerplate code in a one-to-one association relationship

Tags: c++, refactoring, coding-style, boilerplate

Although I'm programming in C++, this is more of a general question about design.

I noticed that when I have objects in a one-to-one association relationship, there tend to be a lot of common methods between them, leading to boilerplate code that essentially directly calls methods of the inner class.

As an example, I have a class called `Tab` that represents a tab and it's corresponding widget. I also have a class called `Tabbable` that objects can inherit, so they can be displayed in tabs. A `Tab` can then take this `Tabbable` object and render itself correctly. Both these classes have a lot of similar methods relating to the title or icon for example.

```
class ITabbable {
    public:
    ITabbable();
    virtual ~ITabbable();

    virtual string getTitle() = 0;
    virtual widget getContentWidget() = 0;


    // etc...
}


class Tab {
    public:
    Tab(ITabbable* tabbableObject);


    // lots of boilerplate code:
    string getTitle() {
        return m_tabbableObject->getTitle();
    }

    widget getContentWidget() {
        return m_tabbableObject->getContentWidget();
    }

    // etc...

    private:
    ITabbable* m_tabbableObject; // association relationship
}
```

A lot of code is duplicated and seems unnecessary. Inheritance definitely doesn't work here because you can't put a `Tab` in `Tab`.

Is this just something we have to deal with? Or are there ways around these situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. To this particular situation. Why not simply implement `Tab::getTabbable()`?

Like this:

```
const ITabbable* Tab::getTabbable() const { return m_tabbableObject; }
```

Then users can do:

```
const ITabbable* obj = tab->getTabbable();
string title = obj->getTitle();
```

You don't have to replicate all functionality.

---

Update: This refactoring is usually called [Remove Middle Man](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/removeMiddleMan.html).